# Why doesn't my <a> tag take me to the specified page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I have a submit button wrapped in an  tag that's meant to submit my form, run a javascript function to save the form in localstorage and take the user to the next page. However, after the form is saved, it does not proceed to the next page. What do?

Here's my html (styled with bootstrap):

```
<a href="bokning_genomford.html">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark py-2 px-4" id="btn">Gå vidare</button>
</a>
```

and here's my javascript function:

```
let bookings = [];
    const addBooking = (ev) => {
      ev.preventDefault();
      let booking = {
        startDate: document.getElementById("startDate").value,
        daySpan: document.getElementById("daySpan").value, 
        packageType: document.querySelector('input[name="packageType"]:checked').value,
        age: document.getElementById("age").value,
        height: document.getElementById("height").value,
        weight: document.getElementById("weight").value,
        shoeSize: document.getElementById("shoeSize").value,
        fname: document.getElementById("fname").value,
        lname: document.getElementById("lname").value,
        email: document.getElementById("email").value,
        tel: document.getElementById("tel").value,
        address: document.getElementById("address").value,
        postalCode: document.getElementById("postalCode").value,
        city: document.getElementById("city").value,
      };
      bookings.push(booking);

      localStorage.setItem('Bokningar', JSON.stringify(bookings));
    };

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", addBooking);
    });
```

I expected wrapping the button in the  tag to send the user to the specified page, but it didn't. If I click the link to the page in vscode using ctrl-click it takes me there, so it's not an issue of spelling. I also tried adding the url to the  tag via the action:"" attribute, and it didn't resolve the issue either.

Comment: A button inside a link [is not valid HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#technical_summary), redirect in the submit handler (set `location.href`) instead of wrapping the button in the `a` element.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the button element and leave the desired text.
It should look like this.

```
<a href="bokning_genomford.html">Gå vidare</a>
```

Button is for submitting a form which you don't use.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I do use a form, I just didn't include it in the HTML because I thought it'd be redundant. I would like to submit my form as well as take the user to the next page.

Comment: In that case in form set action attribute to desired site and set method to get or post and remove <a> element
<form action="bokning_genomford.html" method="get">

Comment: Additionally to what is said in the comment above, you've to remove `ev.preventDefault()` from the event handler in order to allow the form submission.

Answer (score 1):

The content of a `<a>` element cannot be interactive content like a button ([The Anchor element - technical summary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#technical_summary)).

In the end of the submit callback function you can give `window.location` a new value. This will do the redirect. Using the action attribute would also work, but now that you need a GET request to the next page it looks strange if all the values from the form ends in the querystring.

I hope that I will save you some code also to introduce `FormData` and `Object.fromEntries()`. As long as you give all the input elements a name attribute the value will end in the form data object.

```js
let bookings = [];

const addBooking = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let data = new FormData(ev.target);
  let booking = Object.fromEntries(data);
  
  bookings.push(booking);
  // Save to localStorage does not work here, so commented out
  //localStorage.setItem('Bokningar', JSON.stringify(bookings));
  window.location = 'bokning_genomford.html';
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', addBooking);
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label>First name:<input type="text" name="fname"></label>
  <label>Last name:<input type="text" name="lname"></label>
  <button type="submit">Gå vidare</button>
</form>
```